# iOS Google Drive SDK Application-owned Account

Tags: iphone, ios, google-drive-api

I need to read a set of spreadsheets from Google Drive in an iPad app, and these are stored in an account made specifically for the app. So, I stumbled on this https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts which makes total sense. But how am I supposed to use this in iOS? When using a regular account, I couldn't find a method that allows me to set the **refresh token** mentioned in that documentation. The *service account* mechanism looks even more confusing/tricky and there are no code samples in Objective-C. Has anybody got a clue?

Thanks in advance.